# How to convert 2D array one hot encoding to class name label?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I have just trained a CNN model for rock-paper-scissors image classification with Tensorflow. If I try to predict a class of an image, it gives output like `[[1. 0. 0.]]`. How to convert it to a class name label? I use `ImageDataGenerator()` method with `class_mode="categorical"` argument.

Comment: This has been asked multiple times here, please search the site before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the output. A basic one can be as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 3
NUM_CLASSES = 3

one_hot_encoded = tf.constant([[0, 1, 0],
                               [1, 0, 0],
                               [0, 0, 1]])

# Compute the argmax across the columns.
decoded = tf.argmax(one_hot_encoded, axis=1)
```